# Single zcat multiple extracts with IDs arrays

Tags: python, bash, zcat

I have many GB+ size gz archives I can not decompress for disk space reasons. Each archive has one specific identification number (example test365.gz) and a structure like this:

```
         1    1    2 1
##########                 Name:     ZINC000077407198
@<TRIPOS>MOLECULE
 ZINC000077407198      none
@<TRIPOS>ATOM
      1 C1          5.7064    -2.3998   -12.0246 C.3        1  LIG1  -0.1500
@<TRIPOS>BOND
     1    1    2 1
##########                 Name:     ZINC000099999999
@<TRIPOS>MOLECULE
 ZINC000099999999      none
@<TRIPOS>ATOM
      1 C1         -2.0084    -5.2055   -12.9609 C.3        1  LIG1  -0.1500
@<TRIPOS>BOND
     1    1    2 1
##########                 Name:     ZINC000077402345
@<TRIPOS>MOLECULE
 ZINC000077402345     none
@<TRIPOS>ATOM
      1 C1          6.5657    -1.5531   -15.3414 C.3        1  LIG1  -0.1500
@<TRIPOS>BOND
     1    1    2 1
##########                 Name:     ZINC000077407198
@<TRIPOS>MOLECULE
 ZINC000077407198      none
@<TRIPOS>ATOM
      1 C1          3.6696    -1.8305   -14.6766 C.3        1  LIG1  -0.1500
@<TRIPOS>BOND
     1    1    2 1
##########                 Name:     ZINC000012345678
@<TRIPOS>MOLECULE
 ZINC000012345678      none
@<TRIPOS>ATOM
      1 C1          4.5368    -0.8182   -17.4314 C.3        1  LIG1  -0.1500
@<TRIPOS>BOND
     1    1    2 1
##########                 Name:     ZINC000077407100
@<TRIPOS>MOLECULE
 ZINC000077407100      none
@<TRIPOS>ATOM
      1 C1          1.4756    -2.2562   -14.0852 C.3        1  LIG1  -0.1500
@<TRIPOS>BOND
     1    1    2 1
##########                 Name:     ZINC000077407198
@<TRIPOS>MOLECULE
 ZINC000077407198      none
@<TRIPOS>ATOM
      1 C1          6.1712    -0.8991   -16.4096 C.3        1  LIG1  -0.1500
@<TRIPOS>BOND
     1    1    2 1
##########                 Name:     ZINC000077407198
@<TRIPOS>MOLECULE
 ZINC000077407198      none
@<TRIPOS>ATOM
```

The number of lines between the ###### defined block is variable.

I have a list of identifiers for ZINC entities + target archive:

```
test365/    ZINC000077407198
test227/    ZINC000009100000
test365/    ZINC000077407100
...
```

Currently I do:

```
zcat test365.gz | sed -n '/##########                 Name:     ZINC000077407100/,/##########                 Name:/p' > ZINC000077407100.out
```

and I get:

```
##########                 Name:     ZINC000077407100
@<TRIPOS>MOLECULE
 ZINC000077407100      none
@<TRIPOS>ATOM
      1 C1          1.4756    -2.2562   -14.0852 C.3        1  LIG1  -0.1500
@<TRIPOS>BOND
     1    1    2 1
##########                 Name:     ZINC000077407198
```

Which works fine. If there are N blocks for  ZINC000077407100 I extract N blocks upon zcat and do not mind about the line with starting with #####.

The problem is I need to read the archive N times for the N identifiers / ZINC_NUMBER I want the information for. And it takes a lot of time since I have thousands to extract.

So I would like to find a way to pass an array or list of identifiers / ZINC_NUMBER to output the zcat reading to several different files in function of the identifiers in the array / list.

In other words I would like to do single read using zcat and extract data for a set of identifiers and not only one.

Thanks for your help!

Comment: Your question is quite hard to understand. I see `test365.gz` is a GB+ file. Is the issue that you want to look in that file for hundreds of chunks of text and output each one to a different file? Or that you want to search in hundreds of other files each as large as `test365.gz` for hundreds of chunks of text? Or is it something else? By the way, IMHO searching with `sed` is rarely the solution, I suspect `awk` may be better.

Comment: Are you sure the `sed` command posted here is working for you? First of all, I expected the `-n` option as you said you cannot unpack the whole file. Then the sed command has the for `s/a/,/b/p` which throws an error for me. Did you mean `sed -n '/a/,/b/p'`?

Comment: Are you trying to split the large file into multiple smaller files keyed by the ID (e.g., ZINC000077407100.out). Do you need file for each ID, or for a small subset (how many IDs will be retrieved, vs how many Id's in the file) ?

Comment: Also, the 'sed' command will copy all the content of the file, including lines that do not include the pattern. This will take even more space on than the original.

Comment: Last comment: please clarify where are the line ending (the input seems to wrap around).

Comment: Yes sorry it was sed -n I misstyped. To clarify. I have a set of ZINC IDs. Each one has its related data in a si ngle one of the archives. In one archive, a small fraction contains the blocks related to the single ZINC ID. I want to extract in each archive the data for a set of ZINC IDs I am interested in. And store it in separated files (all blocks for one ID in one file). My objective would be to zcat only once for one archive to pipe everything out related to the archive specific ZINC IDs subset I want i  that

Comment: @Dash the sed command as I corrected it works fine. The subset of ZINC IDs I want to extract for one archive is 1-2% (data for one ID in only one archive). And so yes I try to split one archive by ectracting 1-2% corresponding to N IDs in N files each containing a variable number of blocks (the sed match I showed is one block).

Comment: Also if this can help there is about 1 million blocks per archive and each ID has about hundred in a single of them testX ZINC table.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Per OP the requirement is to process large volume of data (millions of rows, multiple GB of data, and the need to retrieve data about 100's of items). Technically possible to do with modern bash, but it unlikely that this will perform well. A better scripting engine will do much better here.

Possible bash/awk solution presented here. It will scan each referenced file once, adn extract all the selected tags with a single pass. Note that the 'tags' lists will be scanned multiple times, but it is implied it's size is reasonable

```
#! /bin/bash -uex
TAGS=data.txt

file_list=$(awk '{ print $1 }' < $TAGS | sort -u)

for f in $file_list ;
do
        gz_name=${f%/}.gz
        zcat $gz_name | awk -v F=$f '
        # Remember tags to retrieve
!DATA && $1 == F { tags[$2] = 1 }
        # OUT set to current output file, empty if item not selected
DATA && $1 == "##########" && $2 == "Name:" {
        OUT = tags[$3] ? $3 ".out" : "" ;
}
OUT { print >OUT }
' $TAGS DATA=1 -
done
```

Needless to say, possible to write the above 5 liner awk job with Python, Perl, Javascript, or your favorite text processing tool. Tested with the sample data set.

Comment: Thanks dash-o. That is awesome and makes it perfectly! You'll save me much processing time and hopefully contribute to the more efficient finding of new drugs that meant to be analogous to such as LSD, psilocin, or other fancy molecules like that :). If you feel creative and want to propose something in python (I use ++) or perl (I use sometimes) or anything else just feel free!

Answer (score 0):

It seems each entry starting with `##########` has always 6 lines. In that case, it would be far easier and more efficient to use `grep -A7` instead of `sed -n /##.../,/##.../p`. I suppose you only printed the subsequent header as it was easier that way (at least when using `sed`). Therefore, I excluded the subsequent header in this answer (`grep -A6` instead of `grep -A7`).

`grep` can be given a list of patterns to search for. This is done with the `-f` option. The list of patterns can be generated from your file. First group by the archive name (e.g. `test365`) and then print all the patterns for that archive. Here we use `awk` to do so. A null byte separates the pattern sections for each archive.

To prevent false positives (and maybe speed up the search a bit) we only search for complete lines instead of substrings. To speed things up we set `LC_ALL=C`. You may also find that `zgrep` is faster than `zcat | grep`.

The following script decompresses each archive at most once.

```
awk -v prefix='##########                 Name:     ' '
  {a[$1]=a[$1] "\n" prefix $2}
  END {for (k in a) print k a[k] "\0"}
' /path/to/your/list.txt |
while IFS=$'\n' read -r -d '' archive patterns; do
  LC_ALL=C zgrep -A6 -Fxf <(printf %s "$patterns") "${archive/\//.gz}"
  # TODO do something with the output for this archive
done
```

In the above script I converted `test365/` from your list to `test365.gz` automatically. I don't know your directory structure. If you need something different, adapt the last argument of `zgrep`. `$archive` iterates over the first column of your (*grouped*) list (*that is, each archive is listed only once*).

From your example code it seems like you want to generate an individual file for each pattern. To do so, replace the loop body from above to

```
zgrep ... > /tmp/zincfound
while IFS= read -r pattern; do
    grep -A6 -Fx "$pattern" /tmp/zincfound > "${pattern##* }.out" 
done <<< "$patterns"
rm /tmp/zincfound
```

Comment: Thanks for thinking about it Socowi I'll keep that in mind. However as I just shortened the input in a stupid way and did not see it made blocks of 6 lines :). The number of lines is variable for each block.

Comment: Similar to generating the patterns for `grep` you can generate the `/…/,/…/p`-patterns for `sed`. However, as you already accepted an answer there is no need to to :)